# C# UWP DataReader exception HRESULT: 0x8000000B

Tags: c#, uwp

I've a problem with C# UWP DataReader: in event action from my remote device, the software raise an exception: **HRESULT: 0x8000000B**....

My remote device sent a simple string ASCII.

Can you help me?

> **Code**

```
UInt32 vid = xxxxxx;
UInt32 pid = xxxxxx;

string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid((ushort)vid, (ushort)pid);

var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs, null);

if (myDevices.Count == 0)
{
  ShowMessage("Device not found!");
  return;
}
else
{
  ShowMessage($"Id: {myDevices[0].Id.Substring(0, 20)}");
  await Task.Delay(500);
}

SerialDevice device = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);

if(device is null)
{
  ShowMessage("Ops...");
  return;
}

ShowMessage($"Port: {device.PortName}\nBaud rate: {device.BaudRate}\nStop bit count: {device.StopBits}\nData bits: {device.DataBits}");
await Task.Delay(500);
using (var dataReader = new DataReader(device.InputStream))
{
  ShowMessage("...");
  await Task.Delay(500);
  ShowMessage("Wait input from device...");

  try
  {
    await dataReader.LoadAsync(1024);

    var receivedString = string.Empty;

    while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
    {
      uint byteRead = dataReader.ReadUInt32();
      receivedString += $"{dataReader.ReadString(byteRead)}\n";
      ShowMessage($"Lettura: {receivedString}");
    }

    ShowMessage($"Message: {receivedString}");
  }
  catch(Exception exception)
  {
     ShowMessage($"Error: {exception.Message}\n{exception.StackTrace}");
  }
}
```

Screenshot exception
[HRESULT:0x8000000B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3TjI.png)

Comment: Hi, we love to help; please [edit] your question and post the exception preferably in English.

Comment: Did you look up the meaning of that error (in Visual Studio, under Tools, pick "Error Lookup").  The error (in English) is: "The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range ".  Most likely you read a byte too far (or something like that).  What type is `dataReader`

Comment: I've edit the question with more code...

Comment: This errors means 'The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range'.